# Text to Morse without using Dictionary

Tags: list, python-3.x, indexing

I am trying to write a program that converts text to morse code using index. I cannot use a dictionary. My code looks like this so far:

```
#Set up variables

alpha = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

morse = ['.-','-...','-.-.','-..','.','..-.','--.','....','..','.---','-.-','.-..','--','-.','---','.--.','--.-','.-.','...','-','..-','...-','.--','-..-','-.--','--..']

#Get input from user

phrase = input('Enter a sentence to be converted to Morse Code')
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with your project. Did you have a programming question? This site is for questions, not a place to dump your progress reports.

Comment: What not use a dictionary? You could use the list indexes, but I see no point. Also your code so far doesn't not really count as an attempt

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new and I'm stuck at this point. I know what I want to do, I just don't know what code to use to accomplish it. I am trying to pull the index value from the "alpha" list and have the program print the same index value, but from the "morse" list. I can't use a dictionary, it has to be done through index

Answer (score -1):

I think you should come up with a solution by yourself since it isn't really a question and you can do it in many ways, one of them is doing 
I think you should come up with a solution by yourself since it isn't a *hard* question and you can do it in many ways, one of them is doing 
 
`For i in len(alpha):
phrase = phrase.replace(alpha[i], morse[i])`